# javascript and messing with the prototype of Strings

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

I'm trying to understand how to manipulate the prototype of the String class. I'm using the following code (which works):

```
String.prototype.reverseIt = function(someStr){
    someStr = someStr.split("");
  var newer = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<someStr.length; i++){
    newer.push(someStr[someStr.length - i - 1])
  }
  return newer;
}

var tester = "hello";

var x = "".reverseIt(tester);

console.log(x);

//Logs an array of "olleh"
```

What I'm trying to understand is, why do I have to have the "" before the invocation of .reverseIt, and how can I write this more effectively so that I can simply call reverseIt and pass it a string parameter without first stating "im a string" by using the "" before reverseIt is called?

Comment: _"how can I write this more effectively so that I can simply call reverseIt and pass it a string "_ `function reverseIt(someStr) {}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adding a method to the `prototype` of an object, you can reference the `this` object inside of said method

```
String.prototype.reverseIt = function() {
    var someStr = this.split("");
    var newer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < someStr.length; i++) {
        newer.push(someStr[someStr.length - i - 1])
    }
    return newer;
}

console.log("hello".reverseIt()); // Actually returns ["o", "l", "l", "e", "h"]
```

Since this returns an array, a `.join("")` call might be necessary at the end of your method.

```
return newer.join(""); // Convert the array to a string, separator character ""
```

---

Side note: If your only goal is to *reverse* the string, try:

```
"Hello".split("").reverse().join("");
```

- `split("")` converts the string into an array of characters
- `reverse()` reverses the array
- `join("")` converts the array back into a string

Answer (score 1):

> how can I write this more effectively so that I can simply call
>   reverseIt and pass it a string

```
function reverseIt(someStr){
    someStr = someStr.split("");
  var newer = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<someStr.length; i++){
    newer.push(someStr[someStr.length - i - 1])
  }
  return newer;
}

String.prototype.reverseIt = reverseIt;

reverseIt("hello")
```

Alternatively, return `String` instead of returning `Array`

```
function reverseIt(someStr) {
  var i = someStr.length, res = "";
  while (--i > -1) { res += someStr[i]};
  // return `String` 
  return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with prototype, you don't have to do it. Inside the method, `this` will refer to the string which called it, so you can call the method on the `tester` string itself instead of passing it as an argument

```js
String.prototype.reverseIt = function() {
  var someStr = this.split("");
  var newer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < someStr.length; i++) {
    newer.push(someStr[someStr.length - i - 1])
  }
  return newer;
}

var tester = "hello";

var x = tester.reverseIt();

document.body.innerHTML = x

//Logs an array of "olleh"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are extending the prototype, all strings will have that function by default, and *this* will be the string you call it on, so you can just do:

```js
String.prototype.reverseIt = function(){
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var tester = "hello";

var x = tester.reverseIt();

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'this' keyword to refer the the string itself.

```
String.prototype.reverseIt = function(){
  someStr = this.split("");
  var newer = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<someStr.length; i++){
    newer.push(someStr[someStr.length - i - 1])
  }
  return newer;
}
```

Invoke like so

```
var tester = "hello";

console.log(tester.reverseIt());
```

In your original function (not using 'this'), you could also call it like this:

```
String.prototype.reverseIt(tester);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```js
    String.prototype.reverse = function(){
      var result = [];
      for(var i = this.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        result.push(this[i])
      }
      return result.join('');
    }
    
    var tester = "hello";
    
    var x = tester.reverse();
    
    console.log(x);
```

Hope this help. However, it isn't a good practice to extend built-in JS classes.

For more on JS prototype, please read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Regards, K.